# Java converting string to date format (yyyy-MM-dd) doesn't give the correct result

Tags: java, hibernate, date

I'm working in spring boot & hibernate:

```
@Entity
public class Flight extends AbstractEntity{
    private Date dateOfDeparture;
    private Timestamp estimatedDepartureTime;
```

My controller : (getting departureDate from jsp.page departureDate is of type text)

```
      @RequestMapping("findFlights") 
      public String findFlight( @RequestParam("departureDate") String d3, ModelMap  modelMap) { 
          DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd"); 
          Date d11 = null;
        try {
            d11 = df.parse(d3);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
      
      java.sql.Date dateOfDeparture =  new java.sql.Date(d11.getTime());
       List<Flight> flights =
              flightRepository.findFlightsByDate(dateOfDeparture);
      modelMap.addAttribute("flights", flights); 
      return "displayFlights";
```

My repository :

```
@Query("from Flight where dateOfDeparture =:dateOfDeparture")
    List<Flight> findFlightsByDate(@Param("dateOfDeparture") Date departureDate);
```

I'm getting no result.whether the dateOfDeparture  is of type java.util.Date or java.sql.Date

can't understand the problem
Thanks for your help

Comment: And you are sure that d3 is not null?

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `Date`, `Timestamp` and `SimpleDateFormat`. All of those classes are poorly designed and long outdated (the latter in particular notoriously troublesome). Instead use `ZonedDateTime`, `DateTimeFormatter` and/or other classes from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: Would you please indent your code properly? Your IDE can do that for you. I misread your code because of incorrect indentation. When misreading your code it is very hard to help you correctly.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Entity
public class Flight extends AbstractEntity{
    private java.sql.Date dateOfDeparture;
    private java.sql.Timestamp estimatedDepartureTime;
```

Considering we have the following utility methods:

```
@RequestMapping("findFlights")
    public String findFlight( @RequestParam("departureDate") String d3, ModelMap modelMap) {
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        Date d11 = null;
        try {
            d11 = df.parse(d3);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        java.sql.Date dateOfDeparture = df.format(d11);
        List<Flight> flights =
                flightRepository.findFlightsByDate(dateOfDeparture);
        modelMap.addAttribute("flights", flights);
        return "displayFlights";
    }


    private final SimpleDateFormat DATE_FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
     
    private final SimpleDateFormat DATE_TIME_FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
     
    private java.sql.Date parseDate(String date) {
        try {
            return new Date(DATE_FORMAT.parse(date).getTime());
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(e);
        }
    }
     
    private java.sql.Timestamp parseTimestamp(String timestamp) {
        try {
            return new Timestamp(DATE_TIME_FORMAT.parse(timestamp).getTime());
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(e);
        }
    }
```